# How to POST Data/Register a User to the Server API using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I just begin in iOS. I'm facing problem in POST the Data to server side. Actually, I have to register a User using the API "https://xyz.php"(random).

here i use the Alamofire Code.

```
        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["name" : nameTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "password" : passTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "school" : schoolTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "class" : classTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "email" : emailTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "mobileno" : mobileTxt.text as AnyObject,
    ]


    Alamofire.request("https://xyz.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in

            print(response)

    }
```

but when I hit the Submit Button it giving me error message in Success Response. Can Any One help me out. To make the user Register. with the given parameter using Alamofire.

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: The error message should hopefully explain what went wrong. What does it say?

Comment: what is error message

Comment: see your dictionary .. 
     let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["name" : nameTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "password" : passTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "school" : schoolTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "class" : classTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "email" : emailTxt.text as AnyObject,
        "mobileno" : mobileTxt.text as AnyObject,
    ]

Comment: you have comma even after your last value. remove this and try

Comment: SUCCESS: {
    message = "E-mail id already exist";
    status = No;
} . this is the response i am getting. Even after entering the unique email id and password. I also delete the data from the beckend team but the issue is same.

Comment: @junaidUmer Brother I removed the last comma. and the issue is still same

Comment: the response should be. like that. Respose Data: {
    class = II;
    email = "adnan@gmail.com";
    "fb_id" = "<null>";
    "google_id" = "<null>";
    message = "Registration Successful.";
    name = "adnan";
    phone = 999999999;
    "profile_pic" = "https://xyz.in/glo/images/profilepic";
    school = Nobile School;
    status = Yes;
    "user_id" = 503;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //  Try this after your parameters, with your URL
 Alamofire.request(your URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
                    {
                        response in
                        //printing response
                        print(response)

                        //getting the json value from the server
                        if let result = response.result.value {

                            //converting it as NSDictionary
                            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
                           UserDefaults.standard.set("password", forKey: "user_id")

                           let userName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_id")
                           }
                        }

               // view controller identifier for your next view controller
     let abcd = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "abcd") as! DetailsViewController

                self.present(abcd, animated: true)

                }
```